# Search for a particular value in xml using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, if-statement

I have XML data which coming from some web service and that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Hospitals>

<Hospital>
<Name>Fortis HealthCare</Name>
<Speciality>Cardiology</Speciality>
<Speciality>Counseling</Speciality>
<City>Mumbai</City>
</Hospital>

<Hospital>
<Name>Sagar Hospital</Name>
<Speciality>General Dentistry</Speciality>
<City>Bangalore</City>
</Hospital>

</Hospitals>
```

I have a two text fields in HTML

```
<form id='search'>
<input type='text' class=''speciality'><br>

<input type='text' class=''area'><br>
<input type='submit' class=''btn'>
</form>
```

Based on this search, I need to get the complete details of hospitals from the XML.

Using jquery I tried to get the value like

```
function parseSearch(xml)
{
 //find every query value
 $(xml).find("Hospital").each(function()
 {
 var cityName = $(this).find("City").text();
 });
}
```

but now how would I search and display the correct data from xml?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
function parseSearch(xml) {
    //find every query value
    $(xml).find("Hospital").each(function () {
        var cityName = $(this).find("City").text();
        console.log(cityName);// check city name in console
    });
}
$(function () {
    $(':submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parseSearch(xml);
    });
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tR7h9/)**

**Updated**

```
function parseSearch(xml) {
    //find every query value
    $(xml).find("Hospital").each(function () {
        if($(this).find('Speciality').length){// check for speciality
           console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
}
```

<kbd>[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tR7h9/2/)</kbd>

Comment: where this will display the xml. Its find cityName, what about whole <hospital> tag in xml it has to get the whole <Hospital> tag data.

Comment: Use `console.log($(this).text());` See http://jsfiddle.net/tR7h9/1/ if you want your tag data as `html` then use `console.log($(this).html());`.

Comment: but it is displaying all the entries, I need to search for a specific one which user provide in the text field. If <speciality> matches in some <hospital>, Display full information

Comment: ok thanks, now i think i can check for conditions, will let you know this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var xml = $.parseXML(yourfile.xml),
  $xml = $( xml ),
  $test = $xml.find('test');
  console.log($test.text());
```

here test is xml node name like hospital.
For help :-  http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

Comment: this will only display hospital text value but in my case hospital tag having sub - tag not text